# How do I convert text block to code block?

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface, npm

I have to create code snippets in UI (like in StackOverflow/bootstrap etc.) where the data is coming from the database.
Suppose my code is:

```
class test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```

I am sending this piece of code exactly like this (with proper tabs and enter) but when I render this in view it becomes a single line. I saw that the data gets stores as a single line in the database.
Is there any way to do this in Angular? I have tried using `pre` but it can't understand where to break line.

Comment: what is your input and your desired output

Comment: The above code snippet is my input and the desired output is to show it like it is viewed now as a perfect code block